# Powershell serial com ports that are actively working and can write and read data

Tags: windows, powershell, serial-port

I'm still a beginner when it comes to powershell scripts. I have looked into a couple different methods but unable to find anything specific to my situation. I have several PC's that have different Com ports assigned. I need a universal program that can run to find the com ports I need and store that as a variable, which will then be later used. I can use getportnames with powershell and get a list of serial com ports.

I would like to systematically go through each one, send a simple "enter" command and read if there is a response. In essence, Find which com port has a response, and assign it as the active com port in a variable. Like for instance below:

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames(

for (
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM(Com ports here), 115200, None, 8, one
$port.Open()
$port.Write (Something here)
$line = $port.Read (Something goes here)
)
if ($line has data) do(things)
```

The most I've been able to do is get the list of ports I have available.

Comment: You should be able to get the info displayed in Device Manager for the port if the manufacture uses standard header block.  Hardware devices in Windows have a header block (including serial ports).  Most meet windows requirement and the header block contains a name.  Others, the name is buried in a manufacturer non standard header.  If you use a manufactures driver than name can always be found (if one exist).  If you use a generic Microsoft Driver then name may not get displayed if the vendor uses a non standard header.

Comment: Okay. So I've mostly got it figured out. I just need to find a way to read it then assign the port based off which port is able to be write/read to.

$ports = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
$ports | ForEach-Object -Process {$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $_,115200,None,8,one;$port.open();$port.WriteLine(Text goes here);}